# The word 'until': 'fought off the Dutch until 1903' _ does this necessarily imply being conquered in 1903?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pragmatics

In Bali, local rulers resisted the yoke of Queen Wilhelmina until 1908. Aceh, at the western extremity of the island chain, fought off the Ducth until 1903.

I think the word 'until' can be interpreted both ways, disregarding history? And if it the case, how do I know how to make that word out without first knowing about the precise history? Or is there other rules that follow in the use of "until" so the ambiguity in meaning is obviated?

Comment: What ambiguity?

Comment: What in the world does "interpreted both ways" mean? Which direction are we facing?

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Did the Balinese kingdoms resist the Dutch until they succeeded, or until they lost? The sentence does not tell us that, but it does say that after those dates there was no resistance, because there is no ambiguity about the word **until**.

Comment: @HotLicks I guess I got a bit confused with simply using 'until' or in the combination of 'not until'. So I do not know whether the locals started to resist in 1908 or whether their resistance stopped in 1908.

Comment: @JohnLawler I explained my puzzlement to Mr licks. Sorry for the vagueness in my own question.

Comment: @WeatherVane victory or defeat was not what I'd concerned. But reading your comment, I kinda knew already the answer, that is, the locals have been resisting until 1908, the action stopped in 1908.

Comment: @user330039 Except that the Dutch subdued Aceh five years earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, logically, 'S did V until T' says nothing about the situation from T onwards.

Pragmatics (a sense of how practised Anglophones actually use the language, sometimes defying logical approaches) informs a reader that a standalone statement

- In Bali, local rulers resisted the yoke of Queen Wilhelmina until 1908.

should be taken as meaning the resistance collapsed and the Dutch Empire was enlarged in 1908. This is the default reading; it would be misleading to use this sentence to mean something different without further information. But *with* further information, the default sense can be overridden:

- In Bali, local rulers resisted the yoke of Queen Wilhelmina until 1908, when an alliance with the mighty Klingons secured their independence for the foreseeable future.